# How to use @Labels spring data neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

It is very confusing for me to use @Labels annotation and its use ? I am following spring-data-neo4j 3.2.2 documentation. And I have found no examples of @Labels annotation. Though in api , there is @Labels annotation is available. Can anyone please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was more ore less experimental and the collection represents the labels on the node and allow you to access them programmatically and also add new labels. I did not yet put in any safeguards for not removing the system labels.